# How to add a new entry in each of the tuple in a list which is collection of tuples in erlang?

Tags: list, erlang, tuples

I have a list like - `[{{1},{2}},{{a},{3}},{{4},{b}},{{5},{6}}]`

And i have a function, which generates series of numbers-

```
getNum()
```

And I have to add the numbers generated from the above API into each of the tuple in the above list.

So the result list should look like-

`[{{1},{2},{10}},{{a},{3},{11}},{{4},{b},{12}},{{5},{6},{13}}]`

Here the entries 10, 11, 12, 13 came from the API getNum().

Can someone help in writing a list comprehension in erlang to achieve this result?

Comment: Does every call to `getNum()` return a single number?

Comment: No. It can give different numbers.

Comment: Yes, of course. My question is if every call to `getNum()` will return a single number or if it will return a tuple or list of numbers. You mention a "series", that's why I ask.

Comment: @LutzHorn: I had in mind of series of single number. However, I think extending it to tuple should be similar.

Comment: Le me try.  Lutz Horn is asking this question:  Does calling `getNum()` once do like its name suggests and return one number, e.g. 10, or does calling  `getNum()` once  return a list of numbers, e.g. `[10, 5, 11, 12]`?

Comment: @7stud: everytime you call that API, it should return a single number, that's what initially I had in my mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

go() ->
   List = [{{1},{2}},{{a},{3}},{{4},{b}},{{5},{6}}],
   [{{X}, {Y}, {getNum()}} ||  {{X}, {Y}} <- List ].


getNum() -> 
    Num = rand:uniform(20),
    io:format("getNum() => ~w~n", [Num]),
    Num.
```

In the shell:

```
8> a:go().
getNum() => 5
getNum() => 17
getNum() => 16
getNum() => 6
[{{1},{2},{5}},{{a},{3},{17}},{{4},{b},{16}},{{5},{6},{6}}]
```

You could also do it like this:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

go() ->
   List = [{{1},{2}},{{a},{3}},{{4},{b}},{{5},{6}}],
   [erlang:append_element(TwoTuple, {getNum()}) ||  TwoTuple <- List ].


getNum() -> 
    Num = rand:uniform(20),
    io:format("getNum() => ~w~n", [Num]),
    Num.
```